# The optimal way to determine if NSManagedObject related attribute object exist

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I got a `log` object retrieved by `NSFetchedResultsController`, it has an optional attribute that's an `slide` object. And it's currently faulted. So if I log `log.slide`, it will return a faulted object. How do I check if log actually have a slide object attached to it? I want to be able to use `if(log.slide){...}`

I tried to set the NSFetchRequest to    `[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];` before hand it to `NSFetchedResultsController`. But it's still returning faulted objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fault is automatically fulfilled when you access it, so you can simply use your example `if (log.slide) {...}` and it will work like you expect it to, fulfilling the fault if necessary.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out the reason it was not working was because I didn't own the log object and it was deallocated when I wanted to use it.